# How can I preserve type-safety when consuming redux-connected React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I've been playing around with TypeScript in a React/Redux/Redux-Thunk project, and I keep hitting this snag where after `connect`ing a component, it doesn't appear possible to sensibly use it without casting it, because the connection process doesn't seem to be able to convey to the type system that some or all of the property requirements have been fulfilled by the connection operation. For example, consider these components/types/etc.:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Action, bindActionCreators, Dispatch} from "redux";
import {ThunkDispatch} from "redux-thunk";

// Our store model
interface Model {
    name: string,
}

// Types for our component's props
interface FooDataProps {
    name: string // Single, required, string property
}

interface FooDispatchProps {
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>, // Single, required, event handler.
}

interface FooProps extends FooDataProps, FooDispatchProps { // Union the two types
}

// Make our first component...
function TrivialComponent(props: FooProps) {
    return (<button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</button>);
}

// Now make a Redux "container" that wires it to the store...
const mapStateToProps = (state: Model): FooDataProps => { return { name: state.name }; };
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): FooDispatchProps => {
    return bindActionCreators({onClick: doStuff}, dispatch);
};

// Wire it up with all the glory of the heavily-genericized `connect`
const ConnectedTrivialComponent = connect<FooDataProps, FooDispatchProps, FooProps, Model>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrivialComponent);

// Then let's try to consume it
function ConsumingComponent1() {
    // At this point, I shouldn't need to provide any props to the ConnectedTrivialComponent -- they're 
    // all being provided by the `connect` hookup, but if I try to use the tag like I'm doing here, I 
    // get this error: 
    //
    // Error:(53, 10) TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<FooProps, never> & FooProps>'.
    // Property 'name' is missing in type '{}'.
    //
    return (<ConnectedTrivialComponent/>)
}

// If I do something like this:
const ConnectedTrivialComponent2 = ConnectedTrivialComponent as any as React.ComponentClass<{}, {}>;

// Then let's try to consume it
function ConsumingComponent2() {
    // I can do this no problem.
    return (<ConnectedTrivialComponent2/>)
}

// Handler...
const doStuff = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<Model, void, Action>, getStore: () => Model) => {
    // Do stuff
};
```

OK, so, in thinking about this problems, I've been through a few ideas:

Idea #1) **Make all props optional.** Many components I've seen from third parties have everything optional, but in my experience having everything be optional leads to a lot of boilerplate nil-checks all over the place, and makes code harder to read.

Idea #2) **Cast to `React.ComponentClass<P,S>`** and create additional types for any properties *not* filled in by the `connect` operation. The cast works obviously, but now you've got three sets of things to keep in sync with one another (the original Props types, the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` lists, and the "leftover Props" types.) This approach feels verbose, error prone, and it also erases other potentially useful type information.

Is there a better way to manage `connect`ed components in terms of types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I think I've figured this out. In the form shown in the question (and note that there are 12 possible call/type patterns of `connect` called out in its type definition file -- this is only one), there are four type parameters to `connect`. They appear to represent:

1. **TStateProps** - a type containing the properties you will populate with the `mapStateToProps` parameter to `connect`. (It is also incidentally the return type of the `mapStateToProps` function)
2. **TDispatchProps** - a type containing the properties you will populate with the `mapDispatchToProps` parameter to `connect`. (It is also incidentally the return type of the `mapDispatchToProps` function)
3. **TOwnProps** - a type containing the properties remaining to be set for the *new* component generated by the `connect` call (this is where my confusion was.) TOwnProps is *also* the type of the `ownProps` parameter to `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.
4. **State** - the type of the Redux store model root.

No. 3 being called `TOwnProps` is a little confusing, because it implies the association with the `ownProps` parameter to the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions. I've never had occasion to use `ownProps` in practice, so I didn't immediately understand that there's actually more to it than that. Doing some more digging, I found that `connect` returns:

```
InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
```

and the definition of that is:

```
export interface InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TInjectedProps, TNeedsProps> {
    <C extends ComponentType<Matching<TInjectedProps, GetProps<C>>>>(
        component: C
    ): ConnectedComponentClass<C, Omit<GetProps<C>, keyof Shared<TInjectedProps, GetProps<C>>> & TNeedsProps>
}
```

Seeing `TStateProps & TDispatchProps` referred to as `TInjectedProps` and `TOwnProps` referred to as `TNeedsProps`, helped snap things into focus a bit more. `TStateProps & TDispatchProps` are the properties "injected" into the wrapped component by `connect`, and `TOwnProps` are the properties that the wrapper still "needs" from consumers of the connected component.

The other realization I had was that the way I had it in the question (i.e.  `connect<FooDataProps, FooDispatchProps, FooProps, Model>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`) makes no sense, because if the third type parameter were (semantically) supposed to represent "all props, state or dispatch" the type system could easily have achieved that by `&`ing `FooDataProps` and `FooDispatchProps` that it got as param #1 and param #2. There would be no new information conveyed by having that third type parameter as I was using it.

[Matt McCutchen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998840/438982), while helpful, focuses only on the role of `TOwnProps` with respect to the `ownProps` parameter to the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions. He correctly observed that I don't use the `ownProps` parameter in those functions, and suggested that I pass `{}`. That answer appears correct for the context it describes, but it neglects `TOwnProps`'s other role as the determinant of what props can be accepted by the higher-order `connect`ed component.

The summary takeaway here is that `TOwnProps` is doing double duty here, not only as a type for the `ownProps` parameter to the map functions, but *also* as a type capturing the properties remaining to be set by consumers of the wrapped/connected component.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the third type argument to `connect` (named `TOwnProps` in the declarations) should be the type of any props used by your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions themselves.  Since your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions do not use any props, you would set this type argument to `{}`, not to `FooProps`, and then the error goes away.  (Removing the explicit type arguments and relying on inference will give you the same end result.)